# how to implement a so that user can login through maximum 2 devices

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am working on a lms site where an user can maximum logged in, in 2 devices. So far I tried this below code where I am modifying my Login method of Login controller.

```
if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {


            if (Auth::user()->role_id == 3) {
                $logout = 0;
                $logins = UserLogin::where('status', 1)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->latest()->get();

                if (count($logins) == 2) {
                    foreach ($logins as $login) {
                        if ($login->created_at->addHours(2) < Carbon::now(env('TIME_ZONE'))) {
                            $login->status = 0;
                            $login->save();
                            $logout = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($logout == 0) {
                        Auth::logout();
                        Toastr::error('Your Account is already logged in, in 2 devices', 'Error!');
                        return redirect()->route('login');
                    }
                }
                //storing login info
                UserLogin::create([
                    'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                    'ip' => $request->ip(),
                    'browser' => Browser::browserName(),
                    'os' => Browser::platformName(),
                    'access_value' => Str::random(12),
                ]);
            }

            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
```

and in logout functions i try this

```
if (Auth::user()->role_id == 3) {
            $login = UserLogin::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('ip', $request->ip())->where('browser', Browser::browserName())
                ->where('os', Browser::platformName())->where('status', 1)->latest()->first();
            if ($login) {
                $login->status = 0;
                $login->access_value = null;
                $login->save();
            }

        }
```

but it will become unnecessary when user close their tabs. Because that time i cannot perform the operation on DB or cannot check for the status.
Note: I tried to use javascript onunload and onbeforeunload but i cannot make it.what i want...PLease help me ..thanks in Advance

Comment: yes...@MagnusEriksson i think you're right...ok if i think about the devices then what can I do...can you give me the hints or some way...Because the user requirements is mainly 2 devices not browsers.

Comment: Not sure about whole question but if you want to send Ajax request in unload there is API for that that will work [Navigator.sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) but while I'm reading the docs it seems that you should not use this API in unload onbeforeunload and use page Visibility change event instead, but it should work fine there.

Comment: thanks for your comment...i will try also that